# I have been taking these pills for 3 days

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have question about using this phrase. For example my doctor told me to take 1 pill every day. Then after 3 days he asked me: how long have you been taking these meds?

I was taking them the 1st day, 2nd, 3rd and today 4th day I took them too in the morning and doctor asked me on 4th day how long have you been taking them. I said

> I have been taking them for 3 days

but I am not sure since I took the pill today too so shouldnt have I said 4 days?

Should I count the on-going day or still not until its fully finished?

Answer (score 5):

You've been taking them for **four days**.

'Have been' is continuous, and since you already took the pill in the morning, it should reflect that in your sentence.